# Aggregate Information within child cells Excel outline level Groupings

Tags: excel, formatting, vba

I am using Excel Outline Levels. the data looks like this.

[image]

I need the red text to be an automated value (possibly looking at multiple levels of children) which will interrogate any child records of a group record and summarise the data. in this case you can see that the three conditions are: 
- if all seats are not occupied, the room is empty, if there are empyt seats its partial, and if all seats are taken its full..

Can you do this with a formuala or do I need to create a VBA function?

Comment: If you can add a column noting the room next to each seat i can suggest an answer? Is this possible even if it's always hidden.

Comment: That's good. My suggestion below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C4` and assuming column A is hidden and has the room noted next to each seat:

```
=If(Countif(A:A, B4) - 1 = CountA(Offset(C4, 1, 0, Countif(A:A, B4) - 1)), "FULL", 
      If(0 = CountA(Offset(C4, 1, 0, Countif(A:A, B4) - 1)), "EMPTY", "PARTIAL"))
```

**Additionally :**

Two points for the above, if you have not labelled cell `A4` to be `Room A`  then remove the `- 1`.

Also once those is done for this one cell simply copy and paste to the other cells and it will automatically reference the correct cells for you using relative referencing.

**If transposed:**

```
=If(Countif(1:1, B2) - 1 = CountA(Offset(B3, 0, 1, , Countif(1:1, B2) - 1)), "FULL", 
      If(0 = CountA(Offset(B3, 0, 1, , Countif(1:1, B2) - 1)), "EMPTY", "PARTIAL"))
```

Comment: Would this work if I transpose the worksheet (ie have the grouped rows become columns?) or do I need to change the offset?

Comment: You will need to change it and will also need an example as your initial example could be transposed many ways. I'll update my answer for a complete transposition.